# How to convert curl request to javascript

Tags: javascript, http, curl

I'm trying to send an HTTP request from my react code to iphub API.

in the document there is an example of how to use in this service:

`curl http://v2.api.iphub.info/ip/8.8.8.8 -H "X-Key: 123"`

I convert the request according to some answers and it looks like this:

```
const ripeEndpoint = 'http://v2.api.iphub.info/ip/8.8.8.8'
fetch(ripeEndpoint, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: new Headers({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'X-Key': myApiKey
  }),
})
```

but the response is 404, I think that my request is wrong, how can I know if the converted request correct?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a _response_ header, trying to specify it as a _request_ header makes zero sense.

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` – why? There is nothing in your cURL command that would cause this to be used.

Comment: Is this API even CORS-enabled …?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up response and request headers.

> A **response header** is an [HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTP_header) that can be used in an HTTP response and that doesn't relate to the content of the message. Response headers, like `Age`, `Location` or `Server` are used to give a more detailed context of the response. ... However, these entity requests are usually called responses headers in such a context.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Response_header

> A **request header** is an [HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTP_header) that can be used in an HTTP request, and that doesn't relate to the content of the message. Request headers, like `Accept`, `Accept-*`, or `If-*` allow to perform conditional requests; others like `Cookie`, `User-Agent` or `Referer` precise the context so that the server can tailor the answer.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header

For a simple `GET` request, you usually do not need any header at all, see [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript) 
In your case, in you `curl` command, you specified a single additional header, and so you might just do that in Javascript as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<?php
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url = 'http://v2.api.iphub.info/ip/'.$ipaddress;
$auth = "OTf4sfpNHUhRM1AwNVMOZlJPSmRseTY0WTFsMGhtR1J0alhEbW=="; 
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["X-Key: {$auth}"]);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```